# Create user control in wpf

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

Please can anyone tell me how to make a `combobox` which contains items as a label controls and each label control has delete button on its left side. If click on delete button this item will be deleted and added to the listbox.

I have tried this but I am not able to do this.

Answer (score 0):

***The Below code is the exactly doing the same. ***

```
<ComboBox Width="100" Height="23">
      <ComboBoxItem>
           <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
              <Button Content="Delete" Click="Button_Click" Name="btn"/>
              <Label Foreground="Red">Red</Label>
           </StackPanel>
      </ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```